# Problems with LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryentry

I am having trouble with LDAP. Now I use this code:

```
DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAPS://*******.com:636", "User@bloom.local", "Password");

ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection);

var result = search.Filter = "(objectClass=*)";
search.FindAll();
```

I spent a large number of experiments, but never received:

> Unknown error (0x80005000)

or

> The server is not operational.

My property in the softerra LDAP Administrator:

[image: Properties]

Comment: Just a question since I'm curious : is this double assignement even legal in C# : `var result = search.Filter = "(objectClass=*)";` ?

Comment: Yes, this is legal, but now it does not matter, it's left of my experimentation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the simple authentication mechanism requires an LDAP distinguished name (DN) and you provided just a user name. At least, this is what your screenshot shows.

The DN of the administrator is likely something like `cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=bloom,dc=local`.

Also, I would probably steer away from using the administrator credentials in production. It is much more preferable to create an account with the right privileges.

Comment: I tried to add a domain, but still get the error.  LDAPS://********.com:636/DC=bloom, DC=local

Comment: Have you tried using a command line client like `ldp.exe` and authenticate that way. I am sure that if you can authenticate using ldp then you should be able to do that via your code as well. I was just guessing the domain name in my answer.